# Standard way of using sine and cosine to find tangent

Tags: trigonometry

There was question I came upon, and I was stumped. The question was: evaluate the sine ,cosine, and tangent of the angle without using a calculator.

I was given $-\pi/6$.
I know that sine is $-1/2$ and cosine is $\sqrt{3}/2$.

Normally I know that $\tan = \sin/\cos$. And doing so gives $-1/\sqrt{3}$.
The problem was that the actual answer is $-\sqrt{3}/3$, and I can't seem to figure out how that can be possible

Comment: $-\frac 1{\sqrt 3} = -\frac {\sqrt 3}{3}$.  Those are both the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are both the same number and the same answer.

$-\frac 1{\sqrt{3}} = -\frac 1{\sqrt{3}} * \frac {\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} = - \frac {\sqrt 3}{3}$.

It's a standard practice (no-one really knows why or has a universal explaination why) for many texts and classes to consider radical signs in the denominator of  a fraction to be taboo and require to be "deradicalized".

I wouldn't worry.  You *did* get the right answer.

Comment: In many cases I prefer the non-deradicalized version, especially if it's just one or two simple radicals at the bottom. Just personal preference though

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$. To see this, rationalise the denominator of the latter by multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt 3$.